# What would be a good way to mix magic and tech?

Tags: technology, magic

I want to create a world that combines both magic and steampunkish technology melding them into two different branches. With a school for each. What would be a good starting point?

Comment: Electromechanical plasma shooting zombie unicorns, just for the rule of cool.

Comment: Hi Matt. Your question is flagged for closure because it basically demands an opinion. It is a good start to a question, but please edit!

Comment: You can improve the question by narrowing down the answers. What is the extent of the magic system? How will you rank answers objectively? What about your world might be important to the people answering, like the climate, land, political systems, etc.? Right now you could write a book about the topic. Please clarify your question with an edit.

Comment: Have a look at Skyrim and the dwarven runes that are present. They feel steampunk ish, but magic is clearly present as well.

Answer (score 1):

**To make it work, keep your magic clear of the tech things that characterize steampunk: energy tech, weapons and transportation.**

Steampunk and technology follow the rules of physics.  A steam powered world is internally consistent and you do not have to make up stuff, just explore aspects of it.

Magic is by definition outside conventional explanations for the natural world.  If you have a world with loads of magic you need to make it from scratch and explain how it works.  For example if you have magic power do you need a big steam boiler?  Why?

To stay out of the way of the tech, magic can be of a sort completely separate from things involving energy, weapons, power and the like - magic might be charms and interpersonal things, necromancy etc.

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to decide what kind of magic you would use and the rules. Then you would need to ask if everyone has magic(but a few are taught) or is it a skill of some minority. This would most likely the ruling class as the presence of magic would retard scientific innovation hence the steampunk tech. Also,does the steampunk tech enable the use of magic.

Its hard to give you a good answer as your question is a bit vague. Additionally, the steampunk tech or magic would have to rise to meet each other (or out pace the other) to generate the conflict for your story.